# Is there any way to make an NSView redraw more frequently?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, drawing, nsview

I currently have some code that does something like this (massively simplified, but enough to illustrate the point):

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet CustomViewClass *customView;

...

for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {

    // Crunch some data (Up to ~200,000 operations)...

    // Update view to represent where we are in the process:
    [_customView setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}
```

Whenever I run the code for a given number of iterations, the custom views drawRect: method is only called one time, once all of the iterations have completed.

What I would like is for the view to be forced to be updated after every iteration, and to wait until the view has been redrawn before going onto the next iteration - but I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how to get it working as I would like!

I feel like if I could simply call drawRect: directly that would solve my problem but I know NSView does not allow this!

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Need to offload the workload  to another thread, or some other approach, or spin the runloop periodically. Which is what allows the ui to update.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have it working now using a combination of GCD to perform the work away from the main thread, and a timer to call the setNeedsDisplay: at a regular interval rather than after every iteration. The only problem I notice now is that if I do something like click and hold on a button while the process is going on, the redrawing of the custom view is prevented until I let go of the mouse! Is there any way I can prevent that from happening?

Comment: @tom1990: You should ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @PeterHosey ok I have just done that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933902/can-i-redraw-a-custom-nsview-while-another-control-on-the-same-window-is-being-u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lack of view updating isn't even the biggest problem with your current approach. The biggest problem is that your application is hung until it finishes. The user cannot cancel (if you have even provided a Cancel button), tell the application to hide, do anything else in the application while the work proceeds, or quit the application.

The correct approach is to move the body of the loop to an NSOperation. You can do this either by subclassing NSOperation or by creating one with a block. Then, throw all the operations into a [queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/).

If what you're doing in the loop can [safely](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) be run in parallel, then you should create a queue and use that one. If you need it to happen one operation at a time, use dependencies to chain each operation to the one before it. If it absolutely must happen on the main thread, you can use the main queue, but you should do the least amount on the main thread that you can safely get away with.

As work proceeds, run some code on the main thread/main queue that tells your view to `setNeedsDisplay:`. Since the operations aren't on the main queue (assuming you didn't put them there), or at least are broken up, this can happen while work is ongoing.

Further reading:

- [Managing Concurrency with NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/ManagingConcurrency/) (a little old, as acknowledged at the top, but still a good introduction)
- [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/)

Comment: @GradyPlayer: NSOperationQueue uses GCD (since Snow Leopard), which in turn will use another thread. The big advantage of NSOperation is that, in my experience, it gets me thinking about how to divide my code into discrete units of work, instead of simply being another way to write “do this later”/“do this in the background”. A useful exercise for the beginner.

Comment: Which *can* use another thread, or can be dispatched on the main thread... But in the abstract I totally agree with you, and up voted your answer.

Comment: @PeterHosey Thank you very much for your detailed response! I am pretty new to cocoa so I still get lost in the framework and documentation from time to time! The for loop I am using was a temporary way of testing the data model was working properly and I was going to implement a way of halting the process in the future. I realised that the application was hanging during the data crunching, and now I realise that was because it was running on the main thread. It does not need to be on the main thread, but the order of operation is important!

Comment: @tom1990: You can add dependencies to an operation object to tell it which other operations need to finish before that operation can run. Do this before adding the operation to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but try use a CVDisplayLink. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1385/_index.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I am not using OpenGL but after taking a look at that article I have had a go at using a timer with my code and it works out well! Despite the amount of operations that the computer is performing it is redrawing very fast! The timer has allowed me to slow it down a little to make the output more useable. What I think I will do now is separate the updating of the model and view so the model updates at unrestricted speed and call setNeedsDisplay: on a timer! Thanks!