# Can I redraw a custom NSView while another control on the same window is being used?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, window, nsview

In a program I am working on I am performing a large amount of data crunching, and want to be able draw a custom NSView to represent the process visually.

The data crunching is processed off the main thread by using GCD (using dispatch_sync as the order needs to be preserved):

```
for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) {

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Add a data crunching task to the queue!
    });
}
```

When the processing is started I initialise a timer, which is used to ask the custom display to redraw at regular intervals (this timer is invalidated once all of the processing tasks are completed):

```
-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {

    [_customView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    // Update some other UI object (labels etc.)    
}
```

I have this working as expected, however the only problem I notice now is that if I do something like click and hold on a button on the same window, or begin dragging a slider while the process is going on, the redrawing of the custom view is prevented until I let go of the mouse!

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening, preferably without moving all of the controls onto a separate window!

Comment: `dispatch_sync` doesn't, in itself, “preserve order”; using it preserves order because `dispatch_sync` waits until the dispatched block returns (this is what “synchronous” means in this context). Thus, you wait for each block to finish before dispatching the next, which means that your loop is exactly the same as a loop that calls each block directly, except that your loop involves a background queue for no effect. To process the blocks serially without blocking the main thread, create and use a serial queue, or use NSOperationQueue and set each operation to depend on the one before it.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. So dispatch_async so I am not hanging on the loop and waiting for a return, but a serial queue to maintain the order on the background thread. Then my GUI updates properly! Thank you very much for taking the time to explain that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yip the timer is on the runloop and while in the drag drop / tracking mode it doesnt get fired because the runloop isnt advanced for the common mode

add it to the modes needed:

```
NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(myTimerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode: NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
```

edit: the runloop is basically apple's while loop for dispatch ANY event to an app. and it filters the events it dispatches based on so called modes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea about that. I though it might have been the the setNeedsDisplay: being prevented. That has solved the issue with other UI controls interfering with the timer. There is one other issue still - if I try and resize the window the update becomes choppy, and if I begin resizing and stop with the mouse still held down the display will not redraw until I let go. Is this a problem with the windows drawing behaviour during resize?

Comment: @tom1990: It's a problem with you waiting on a bunch of number-crunching in between mouse-tracking events. Do it asynchronously and have your block dispatch back to the main thread to signal that a UI update is needed.

Comment: he does it async.. what do you mean?

Comment: @Daij-Djan: Not in the code in this question, he doesn't. I elaborated in a comment on the question.

Comment: blush sorry of course you are right. I did only read "the data crunching is processed off the main thread by using GCD..."

Comment: @tom1990 so yeah dont do it sync do it async. maybe use a serial queue to make the order

Comment: Got it! Thanks for all the comments -  I can now clearly see how little sense my original code makes! dispatch_sync to a concurrent queue...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the question, answers and comments.

Use of NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode has solved my case that constantly redrawing an OpenGL view with given parameters.

```
class MyOpenGLView: NSOpenGLView {

  var timer: Timer?

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0/60, repeats: true) { (t) in
      self.needsDisplay = true
    }

    let runloop = RunLoop.current
    runloop.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
    // runloop.add(timer!, forMode: .eventTrackingRunLoopMode)
  }

  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    // draw moving 3D-cubes
  }

}
```

Now it keeps drawing even I am dragging a slider to update its parameters. Additionally, resizing window has become smooth.

For other solutions "Do it asynchronously," interesting! I will give it try later. Thanks!

**EDITED:**

I have changed my mind to use NSRunLoopCommonModes (RunLoopMode.commonModes), instead of NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode.

Both works well, but Apple's document implies that Common Modes is better in my case.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html